# How good can Nearest Neighbor, Naive Bayes and a Decision Tree classifier solve the given classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, decision-tree, nearest-neighbor

The 3 diagramms (i), (ii), (iii) [image: here] show training sets having 2 numerical attributes (x and y axis) and a target attribute with two classes (circle and square).

**I am now wondering how good the data mining algorithms (Nearest Neighbor, Naive Bayes and Decision Tree) solve each of the classification problems.**

I suppose that the **Naive Bayes** (with the naive assumption that the attributes are uncorrelated) solves the second problem better than (i) and (iii) because here the numerical attributes tend to be more independent from each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*If you want to use each of given methods on such scenarios:*

**First one** could be solved best with a **decision tree** approach cos classes can separate by axises. I mean draw a perpendicular line on x axis that separates values into left and right side and draw another line perpendicular on y axis so you will see that classes will be separated well.

**Second one** can be considered as a **Naive Bayes** problem as you mentioned.

**Third one** can be solved with **k nearest neighborhood** approach. Square classes are at near positions on coordinate system and circle classes can be classified with some error too.

Comment: I think that the SVM-radial should perfectly work with these data also

Comment: I think case 2 above is NOT a good fit for NB, because the distribution of classes on each axis is highly dependent on the other. Running WEKA on a similar data set yields around 50% classification rate, as expected. In fact, I think I'll frame this into another answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think the Decision tree is performs best for (i) and (iii) because in (ii) one would need a diagonal border to separate the classes which would result in a single condition for every point on this seperating diagonal. Because a condition in DT results in either a horizontal or vertical borderline.

Comment: i think k-nn won't be good idea for third classification problem as the dataset resembles to a concentric circle. I think one needs to perform feature engineering on this dataset and then apply the model. Because with k-nn one can get into the problem of underfitting.